# Change Value in MySQL Table Based on Date-Range

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I'm trying to change the status of a post from 'Inherit' to 'Published', but only for posts with dates between 08/01/2012 & 10/08/2012. Would this be the proper query to run to achieve this?

```
UPDATE wp_posts set post_status = replace(post_content, 'inherit', 'published') WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2012/08/01 00:00:00.000' AND '2012/10/08 23:59:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `post_status` is a single value, you needn't do a `REPLACE()` on it. Just set it to the new value.  And MySQL dates should be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss` as in `2012-08-01 00:00:00`

```
UPDATE
  wp_posts
/* Set to the new status */
SET post_status = 'published'
WHERE
  /* Include the old status in the WHERE clause */
  post_status = 'inherit'
  AND post_date BETWEEN '2012-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-10-08 23:59:00'
```

The `REPLACE()` method, although it would work, would likely result in a much slower query since the replacement operation would take place in *every* row, but only actually have an effect on rows which included the string `inherit`.

Comment: This worked great, thanks for the tip on alternatives for "replace()"!